# how to over-ride text box classname in drupal

Tags: theming

By default text box class name is : class="form-text"
i want to over-ride the class name, with some othername.
how to over-ride ? Can any one give the suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Please don't duplicate questions you've already asked; if you have additional information that may help someone give a quicker or better answer, please edit it into the original.